# Issue With Selenium and ChromeDriver in Intellij

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

**I've added the selenium jar files and everything seems to be fine. When I run the program I get**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.<init>(DriverService.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.<init>(ChromeDriverService.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at sneakerbot.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

Please help me. I am stuck and new to using selenium. I'm on a mac and I'm pretty sure everything is up to date.

Comment: It seems your project missing Guava dependency. `ImmutableMap` is a part of this Google collection library. You need to add it explicitly.

Comment: can you please tell me how?? I've been trying to figure that out for the past 3 hours. I don't understand how that's missing in the first place. Please help.

Comment: What build tool do you use for your project? Maven? Gradle?

Comment: I'm just using a standard Java template in Intellij. I did not use Madle or Gradle. Is that the only way it will work?

Comment: No, you can add Guava jar manually in IDEA, just grab one from Maven Repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/29.0-jre
However, using build tools make managing dependencies a way easier.

Comment: wow thank you so much. That took care of it. Now the last thing is I just need to somehow get the chromedriver in the right path. Do you know how to do that? Thank you again wow

Comment: Chormedriver could be placed wherever you want. You only need to specify this place using system properties: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/your/chromdriver/binary");`

Comment: I'm doing exactly that but it's still giving me this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"); Im doing that. It says this ::   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/uhrora/Sneakerbot/C:\Downloads\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Please, share the part your code

Comment: So appartently I got that to work but now I got a whole new issue like the original one.             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.ConnectionPool

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient$Factory.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:116)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault(HttpClient.java:66)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<clinit>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:47)

Comment: Hi greenlt, on MacOS you **don't** have to specify **.exe** extension. This is needed **only** in Windows. Moreover, you can find the needed libraries for Selenium on the [site](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/), go to **Java** and press the [Download link](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-java-3.141.59.zip). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest code to use Selenium with Java (Working in Intellyj). Take a look on the firefox driver path "geckodriver".

First you need to create a new maven project and put this pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>eus.ehu.selenium.tutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestingIzapide</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.13</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Next create a Java class with this code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GoogleSearchTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GoogleSearchTest.class.getName());

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./src/test/resources/firefoxdriver/geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGooglePage() {
        String searchWord="Hello world";
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.clear();
        searchBox.sendKeys(searchWord);
        searchBox.submit();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        LOGGER.info("Alert: TITLE: "+ driver.getTitle());
        assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle());
        LOGGER.info("Alert: TITLE: "+ driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Hope this code helps to start a new project. If you are new in Selenium and comfortable with python I'd recommend you to use Python, but is a personal choice...

cheers

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. Do I replace everything in pom with what you have or add it to the bottom? It was confusing.

Comment: This method isn't working for me unfortunately. Is there anyway you can help me set it up?

Comment: Start a new Java proyect, indicate is a Maven project, and then paste this POM.

Comment: sorry by the delay, i've uploaded a test for you, download it and import into Intellij-Idea: https://github.com/acuartango/SeleniumFirstTestJava

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should start by setting your project up using any modern build tool such as [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). Of course, it is possible to add every dependency manually by downloading jar and attaching it to the project. However, it is a very inconvenient and complicated way. Build tools will manage your dependencies for you as well as run your tests and create reports.

You can use Maven, as @nugbe already suggested. Personally I'd prefer Gradle.

Here is a simple and straightforward solution:

- Create a new Gradle project in IDEA, see [this instruction](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html) for details. You should get a project skeleton for tests.
- Now, it's time for your dependencies. The main source of the common java libraries is [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/). Open it, search for the *Selenium*, then select *Selenium Java* in the results, then click on the desired version ([3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59) is the most recent and stable). On its page, look for Gradle tab, click it and copy artifact URI: `compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'`
- Next, open your `build.gradle` file, look for `dependencies { ... }` section and paste your dependency.
- Btw, you may also orchestrate browser drivers with [WebDriverManager](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/4.0.0). Add this dependency to your project and you'll be able to get actual driver directly from your code with only two lines:

```
     WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
     ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

- After adding all desired dependencies, update your Gradle project: click on the Gradle icon on the right side of the main window, and click *Reimport All Gradle Projects*:

[image]

- Now, you should be able to create your test. So, create new java class in `src/test/java` folder, e.g. FirstTest.java

```java
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class FirstTest {
    private static ChromeDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.clear();
        searchBox.sendKeys("Selenium");
        searchBox.submit();
    }
}
```

- And finally, you can run your test. You can either click on the green triangle next to the test method name in IDEA editor or open the terminal (look at the bottom of the IDEA window) and type: `gradle clean test` and here we go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Selenium project with no worries also as simple Java program.

The needed libraries for Selenium are on their [site](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/), go to **Java** and press the [Download link](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-java-3.141.59.zip).

Then, put all the `.jar` files (they are 7: 2 in the root folder and 5 in `libs` folder) in another folder in your project.
Once done, go to **File** → **Project Structure...** → **Libraries** → **New Project Library** → **Java** → select your folder with the 7 libs and you're done.

Talking about the [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.138/), in your case, on MacOS you **don't** have to specify **.exe** extension. This is needed **only** in Windows.

For doing so, you have to write:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver");
```

(I put all the drivers in the folder "drivers" in my project, at the same level of the folder "src".)

That's all.
Cheers.